# React Component's children testing with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have this Component:

```
export const MyComponent= ({ children, style }: Props) => (
  <p className="component-class-name" style={style}>
    {children}
  </p>
);
```

and I'm trying to test it, so I think there was two cases in the test, one with children, and second is without. Here is my 'with children' test snippet:

```
  it("should render properly with children", () => {
    const children = <span>MyComponent children</span>;
    const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent {...props}>{children}</MyComponent>);
    expect(wrapper.find(".component-class-name").exists()).toBe(true);
    expect(wrapper.find("span")).toHaveLength(1);
  });
```

but I think there is better way to test children. Is it okay or I'm doing something wrong? For testing I use Jest and Enzyme.

Answer (score 0):

```
    it("should render  MyComponent without children", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent {...props} />);
     expect(wrapper.find(".component-class-name").text()).toBe(""); 
   });
```

So, you can test without children.

Comment: " Is it okay or I'm doing something wrong?"
I think, it is ok.